# Resetting keys of resultant array of array_diff()

Tags: php, arrays

In my application I am using array_diff function as -

```
$aDeleteCountryCodes = array_diff($aCurrentCountryCodes, $aNewCountryCodes);
```

Now what happens is, the resultant array, $aDeleteCountryCodes, some times comes as

```
Array
(
[2] => 213
)
```

and some times

```
Array
(
[2] => 213
[3] => 355
)
```

which messes my for loop that I use to delete records from database. For loop is like this-

```
for ($i=0; $i <= count($aDeleteCountryCodes); $++)
{
   // Delete record $aDeleteCountryCodes[$i]
}
```

what I want is the array to come as -

```
Array
(
[0] => 213
)

Array
(
[0] => 213
[1] => 355
)
```

so that the looping becomes easier. I hope I made it clear. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values).
2. Use `foreach` instead of "manual `for` loops."

Answer (score 2):

Rather than reset the keys, it's preferable to just iterate over the existing keys:

```
   foreach ($aDeleteCountryCodes as $key => $value) {
     // delete goes here.
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use array_values(array_diff($aCurrentCountryCodes, $aNewCountryCodes));

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the values out into a new array:

```
$aDeleteCountryCodes = array_values($aDeleteCountryCodes) //Keys resetted.
```